# application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: never called

Tags: iphone, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I'm developing an iOS app with Urban Airship push notifications

I've seen that after these logs:
"Updating device token
Skipping device token update: no token, already up to date, or user is being updated."

Must come this log:
"Device token registered on Urban Airship successfully."

I don't receive the latter.

This function is never called:
application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you,
Nur

=====EDIT======

I followed the [UrbanAirship tutorial here](https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started%3a+iOS%3a+Push)

Here's the code I'm using:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    NSMutableDictionary *takeOffOptions = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    [takeOffOptions setValue:launchOptions forKey:UAirshipTakeOffOptionsLaunchOptionsKey];
    [UAirship takeOff:takeOffOptions];
    [[UAPush shared] updateAlias:@"some_alias"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}

 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    [[UAirship shared] registerDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
```

Comment: We will need to see some code, with the information given it's just guess work. The code for `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` would be interesting.

Comment: @onnoweb How? I tried Angry IP Scanner - all iPhone ports are blocked... How do you port scan your iPhone? Thanks, Nur

Comment: That port needs to be open in the firewall of the network you're connecting to. Many corporate networks block that port. Apple uses it to send the device token to the device.

Comment: Check you provision: do you have last version? It would be better to re-save you provision with enabled Push notifications (Provision Portal) and download it again.
Also check method:
`-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error`

Comment: no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application

Comment: @OdNairy You helped me with catching the error - I didn't think about it myself and I will conduct harakiri for that!! This particular problem has many answers around SO. THANKS!!! :)